# Twitter Streaming API rate limit..How to deal with it?

Tags: java, twitter

Will Twitter Streaming API stream run uninterrupted if the I left this code running for around 3 weeks? Or do I need to keep track of rate limit and if I do how could I do that?

```
 import twitter4j.*

 public class SimpleStream {
 public static void main(String[] args) {
    ConfigurationBuilder cb = new ConfigurationBuilder();
    cb.setDebugEnabled(true);
    cb.setOAuthConsumerKey("******");
    cb.setOAuthConsumerSecret("*****");
    cb.setOAuthAccessToken("********");
    cb.setOAuthAccessTokenSecret("******************");

    TwitterStream twitterStream = new TwitterStreamFactory(cb.build()).getInstance();

    StatusListener listener = new StatusListener() {


        @Override
        public void onStatus(Status status) {
            User user = status.getUser();


            String username = status.getUser().getScreenName();
            System.out.println("Screen name: " + username);

            String name = status.getUser().getName();
            System.out.println("User's real name: " + name);

            long user_id = status.getUser().getId();
            System.out.println("Users_id: " + user_id); 

        }

    };

    twitterStream.addListener(listener);
    twitterStream.sample();


    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add RateLimitStatusListener to track if limit is reached,

```
twitterStream.addRateLimitStatusListener( new RateLimitStatusListener() {
    @Override
    public void onRateLimitStatus( RateLimitStatusEvent event ) {
        System.out.println("Limit["+event.getRateLimitStatus().getLimit() + "], Remaining[" +event.getRateLimitStatus().getRemaining()+"]");
    }

    @Override
    public void onRateLimitReached( RateLimitStatusEvent event ) {
        System.out.println("Limit["+event.getRateLimitStatus().getLimit() + "], Remaining[" +event.getRateLimitStatus().getRemaining()+"]");
    }
} );
```

Also Check twitter-faq section on 'rate limits':  https://dev.twitter.com/docs/faq#6861

***How are rate limits determined on the Streaming API?**

The public streaming APIs cap the number of messages sent to your client to a small fraction of the total volume of Tweets at any given moment.

The sample hose, as documented in https://stream.twitter.com/1/statuses/sample.json, delivers a random sampling of all Tweets at a volume equal to the public streaming cap.

Filtered streams return all matching Tweets up to a volume equal to the streaming cap. If there are more tweets that would match your criteria, you'll be streamed a rate limit message indicating how many tweets were not delivered.*